# Reading a file line by line

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have a file that looks like:

```
@ATDGGSGDTSG
NTCCCCC
+
nddhdhnadn
@ATDGGSGDTSG
NTCCCCC
+
nddhdhnadn
```

Now its a repeating pattern of "4" lines and I every time want to print only the 2nd line i.e. the line after the line starting with "@" i.e 2nd line..6th line..etc.

How can I do it?

Comment: Given the tags you've added to your question I suppose you are not interested in a python solution?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to print all the lines that do not start with @, but are in capitals?

Comment: This is a CROSSPOST. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490607/reading-line-by-line-in-perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible solutions to the problem. With `awk`, the following line fits the requirements:

```
awk '{if ((NR+2) % 4 == 0) print $0}'
```

Test:

```
$ cat test.txt
@ATDGGSGDTSG
NTCCCCC
+
nddhdhnadn
@ATDGGSGDTSG
NTCCCCC
+
nddhdhnadn

$ awk '{if ((NR+2) % 4 == 0) print $0}' test.txt
NTCCCCC
NTCCCCC
```

It displays every 4th line starting from line 2 (because the logical expression ((NR+2) % 4 == 0 is true, where NR contains the actual row number).

If your input happens to have these empty lines in between, then the problem is about displaying the 3rd line and then every 8th.

```
awk '{if ((NR+5) % 8 == 0) print $0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun. Here is a python implementation that is understandable for beginners. It solves your problem, but does not as such aim at printing the 2nd line and all its fourfolds, but uses the characteristics of that line.

```
# you can of course also read this from a file
test_string = """
   ...: @ATDGGSGDTSG
   ...: 
   ...: NTCCCCC
   ...: 
   ...: +
   ...: 
   ...: nddhdhnadn
   ...: 
   ...: @ATDGGSGDTSG
   ...: 
   ...: NTCCCCC
   ...: 
   ...: +
   ...: 
   ...: nddhdhnadn
   ...: """

# put it into a list
test_li = test_string.split()

# output your list
print test_li 
['@ATDGGSGDTSG',
'NTCCCCC',
 '+',
 'nddhdhnadn',
 '@ATDGGSGDTSG',
 'NTCCCCC',
 '+',
 'nddhdhnadn']

 # select the lines you are interested in
 for line in test_li:
    if line.startswith('@'):
        continue
    if line == '+':
        continue
    if line.islower():
        continue
    print line
```